# Firefox pop-up PHP session variable not being sent correctly

Tags: javascript, php, session, firefox, popup

Everything is working fine in Chrome, but not in FF. Here's my situation:

Parent page has a link, on click it creates a pop-up with a text field.
That information is stored in `$_SESSION` and is used to navigate (ie, "one" takes you to page one, "two" takes you to page two, etc.). In the pop-up, on submit three things happen:

1. The textfield info is stored in session.
2. The Parent page refreshes using text field data to tell it where to go.
3. The pop-up closes.

Keep in mind, this is working fine in Chrome. However, in FF I believe it is closing the pop-up window before the info is sent to parent window, thus losing `$_SESSION` data. I believe this because if I make it so the pop-up doesn't close, it works fine, so it's not a case of the pop-up not sending the data back to parent window.

SO...
I think my problem is in the order that my JavaScript is being executed, even though my ordering appears correct. And again, it functions in Chrome just fine.

Here's my code, can you solve it?

(All pages have `$_SESSION` in header, etc, it's not a syntax problem)

I believe Firefox is closing the pop-up before the `$_SESSION` data is being sent! I don't know why! What happens is my browser ends up in `navredirect.php`, with no an empty session. It's not getting the `$_SESSION data`, so the PHP if statement doesn't tell it do the meta redirect. PRINT_R yields nothing.

Parent page pop up call:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="window.open('enternav.php', 'Pop Up',  'width=432,height=270,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,screenX=200,screenY=200,left=200,top=200')">Go to Page</a>
```

Code for pop up page.  (enternav.php)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function proceed(){
           opener.location.reload(true);
           window.opener.location.href='http://www.page.com/navredirect.php';  
           self.close();
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post"  onsubmit="proceed()" action="logscript.php">
<input type = "text" name="page"  />
<input type ="submit" value="Go to page" />
</form>
</body>
```

Code for logscript.php (turns text-field into session data)

```
<? $_SESSION['pw'] = $_POST['page']; ?>
```

Code for navredirect.php (

```
<?
if($_SESSION['pw'] == "one") {
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=pwone.php\">";
} 
elseif($_SESSION['pw'] == "two") {
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=pwtwo.php\">";
} 
else {
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=wrongpw.php\">";
} 
?>
```

Comment: I haven't dug too deep, but if you have the parent window close the child when its location is changed, rather than have the popup close itself, that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. It sounds like it would be tricky to code that in, but definitely worth a shot. I'd like to just have it close onsubmit, but I'll keep it mind.

Comment: You can use an event listener triggered by the `window.onbeforeunload` event. that event is primarily designed to allow "are you sure?" alerts, so make sure you [read up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) on the way it's used.